# PHP file to exec() another PHP file and use the returned data

Tags: php

The file displaypage.php looks like this:

```
<?php

exec("php filetoexecute.php 2>&1",$output);
print_r($output);

?>
```

The file filetoexecute.php looks like this:

```
<?php

echo "test data";

?>
```

The only thing in my $output array is `PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN is not valid`, and I'm not getting much help online. I know why it's there, I'm redirecting STDERR to STDOUT, but why is the text `test data` not being written to the array?

I know that it will work, as long as I don't want to retrieve the output. The code in filetoexecute.php will execute properly (let's say I have it write something to a database) if the line in displaypage.php looks like this:

```
exec("php filetoexecute.php >/dev/null");
```

This, of course is because the output is being dumped to nothing.

I'm doing this because I need filetoexecute.php to operate under a different php session cookie than the file calling it. I can't just switch sessions for the few lines of code processed by filetoexecute.php. I need to know what the results of filetoexecute.php are, that's why I need the data it produces.

Also, `passthru()` doesn't seem to be helping me at all.

Lastly, I'm not married to the idea of using exec() or passthru(), tips on something that would accomplish what I want would be appreciated!

Comment: It's probably easier to simply use file or stream to talk to the parent process (`displaypage.php` for your case).

Comment: @Patrick i run your program on my localhost and its outputting correctly the " Array ( [0] => test data )  " as a result...with error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: @uzyn could you expand on that a bit? I'm not sure what you mean...

Comment: @swapnesh I was afraid of something like that. I'm running on a GD shared hosting server w/ dedicated IP, and I was thinking they may have something locked down or turned off, but I don't know what since it works when I don't require the data to be passed back.

Comment: @Patrick yes this may the case that being in the shared hosting they might have block exec() to execute an external program

Comment: @swapnesh But if I redirect all output to /dev/null, the file executes just fine. So it does work, it's just when I'm trying to retrieve the output data that it throws the error.

Answer (score 0):

After much experimentation, I have found something that works. I don't understand it yet as I'm not familiar with the CLI, and really don't have much use to be, but here is what works:

displaypage.php

```
<?php

$returnedData = exec("php filetoexecute.php &");

echo $returnedData;

?>
```

For whatever reason, the ampersand at the end is what causes exec() to return whatever is output by the page being called. I don't know if this is the best way to accomplish this, but it's working for me now. If you have any suggestions for doing this better, I'd love to know.